# How do I remove an "articles" slug from custom post type in WordPress

Tags: wordpress, url-slug

Our core website is not hosted through Wordpress, however we got a plugin to host a knowledge base. (we wanted the url to be example.com/knowledge-base/)

We put everything into a subdirectory and populated Wordpress with our content.

The plugin, and evidently all KB plugins, was forcing us to add an "article" slug into the URL.

So the URL looked like this:

example.com/knowledge-base/article-slug/post-name

We can find absolutely no way to get rid of the article slug either in WordPress or via the KB plugin slug settings. None of the setting allowed it to be removed. [image: slug settings].

While we can obviously change what content we put into that slug, we couldn't remove it. It adds no value to SEO and if anything is detrimental to it by forcing the keywords further from the front.

Does anyone know how to remove that slug specifically?

We simply want a clean url of example.com/knowledge-base/post-name

Answer (score 1):

After 3 weeks of back and forth with the plugin owner, and trying many weird things, we eventually came across [this plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-slug-from-custom-post-type/) which lets you remove a slug from custom post type.

The only reason this was an issue is because the KB sat in a subdirectory off our main domain which is not hosted on Wordpress. If our site needed much less functionality and we hosted with Wordpress this would never have been an issue - we simply would have named the article slug "knowledge-base".